# Issue in encoding password with spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using grails 2.3.0 and facing the weird issue when encoding the password with spring security:

This is my method to encode password:

```
String encodePassword(String password) {
    return springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
}
```

and using like that

```
log.debug encodePassword("mkb")
log.debug encodePassword("mkb")
log.debug encodePassword("mkb")
```

I am encoding the same password several times and each time I am getting the different encoded password.

logs:

```
$2a$10$h8T4BxgOeozmH/VSPJl7NeTaF2P0iONpSdqDN7dDFFAG.sy8WG/8K
$2a$10$a7qybaiLF/eNrTSwFohjkezNaJTTDdMEinRYKjxDzEt.OoxaIgFOu
$2a$10$nZVhUT0QTmmbtt22CPtM..cLxU252RGBIMkd5aSd2AFXNTNLQ./6u
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's fine. Looks like you're using BCrypt password hash, this algorithm uses random salt each time you encode password (other hashing algorithms use a 'salt source property', like id). This salt is prepended to hash

So you have:

- `$2a` - salt version
- `$10` - rounds
- `$h8T4BxgOeozmH/VSPJl7NeTaF2P0iONpSdqDN7dDFFAG.sy8WG/8K` - Base64 for salt+hash, where salt get first 24 characters, and hash takes the rest:

  - `h8T4BxgOeozmH/VSPJl7NeTaF`  - salt
  - `2P0iONpSdqDN7dDFFAG.sy8WG/8K` - hash (10 rounds for salt + password)

See Spring Security's BCrypt sources: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.java

If you need to check user password manually, you have to use `passwordEncoder`, like:

```
//dependency injection
def passwordEncoder

//validate
String enteredPassword = params.password
User user = ...
if (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, enteredPassword, null)) { //validates raw password against hashed
   //... wrong password entered
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to? Isn't it sufficient that the passwords are hashed and that you can login?

Comment: I am implementing password reset functionality for which I need to check my current saved password with current password entered by the user.

Comment: Thanks @Igor and @Burt. `passwordEncoder.matches` doesn't work in my case(I have injected the passwordEncoder bean), may be I am doing something wrong. `passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(encodePassword('mkb'), 'mkb', null)` gives me the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, just figured out that `matches` is from SS version 3.1. the plugin uses SS 3.0. Btw, `passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(encodePassword('mkb'), 'mkb', null)` doesn't compare with stored password, maybe you mean `passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, 'mkb', null)`?

Comment: Yes you are right I mean `passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, 'mkb', null)`. `passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(encodePassword('mkb'), 'mkb', null)` is just for testing. 
Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Grails spring security describes the process of updating a password at: https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/4.0.x/index.html

```
    User user = User.findByUsername(username)
   if (!passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.password)) {
      flash.message = 'Current password is incorrect'
      render view: 'passwordExpired', model: [username: session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME']]
      return
   }

   if (passwordEncoder.matches(password_new, user.password)) {
      flash.message = 'Please choose a different password from your current one'
      render view: 'passwordExpired', model: [username: session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME']]
      return
   }
```

Where password or new_password are parameters or method arguments